# Why does Remix does not show the description of the error anymore?

Tags: solidity, remix, error, require, revert

I am trying to run one of the methods of my smart contract using `Remix` and I am getting the following:

[image]

Why is not possible anymore to see if this is failing on a `require`, with the right description of the error? It used to be that way.

It is very hard to know what is going on with my smart contract with these kind of errors. Is there a way to enable this back?

```
    require(lockUntil > block.timestamp, "lockUntil must be greater than the current block height");
```

I want to see the second part of the `require` if that's the problem, not just this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have observed this. It got really bad to correct errors and debug now. Before, everything was better. That update they made was really bad.

They made this update and a solution (mandatory) is to send the transaction to the network for debug.

I even contacted them via email. I'm talking to see if they can fix this.

Comment: Awesome, hope you can get a reply soon and share some details. Thank you.

Comment: After a few emails I've sent them, this issue seems to be fixed.

Comment: Just checked and that is correct. Thank you so much for taking the time.